# How to use COUNTIF formula using google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to mimic the countif function using google scripts. However, I got lost on how to mark the Results column D. If there is better way to handle this, please advise.

Formula:
={"Status";ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A),IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))=1,"Request1","Request2"),))}

Ideal Result:

- If the email address is not the same as next row, mark it as "Parent"
- If the email address is the same as the next row, mark it as "Child"

[image]

```
 function checkStatus() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX');
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    
      var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var startrow = 2;
    
      var datarange = sheet.getRange(startrow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, lastCol);
      var dataVal = datarange.getValues();
    
      var nextEmailAdd = '';
      var Array = [];
    
      for (var i = 0; i < dataVal.length; i++) {
        if (i < dataVal.length - 1) {
          nextEmailAdd = dataVal[i + 1][0]
        } else {
          nextEmailAdd = ''
        }
        var EMAIL = dataVal[i][0];
        var USERNAME = dataVal[i][1];
        var ITEM = dataVal[i][2];
        var STATUS = dataVal[i][3];
    
        if (EMAIL && USERNAME && ITEM && STATUS == "") { continue; }
        if (nextEmailAdd != "" && STATUS == "" && nextEmailAdd == EMAIL) {
          STATUS = "Child";
        }
        if (nextEmailAdd != "" && STATUS == "" && nextEmailAdd != EMAIL) {
          STATUS = "Parent";
        }
      }
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 4).setValues(STATUS);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code on loop with these :

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataVal.length; i++) {

  var EMAIL = dataVal[i][0];
  var USERNAME = dataVal[i][1];
  var ITEM = dataVal[i][2];
  var STATUS = dataVal[i][3];

  if(i==0)
  {
    STATUS = "Parent";
  }
  else
  {
    if (i < dataVal.length - 1) {
      prevEmailAdd = dataVal[i -1][0]
    } else {
      prevEmailAdd = ''
    }

    if (prevEmailAdd != "" && STATUS == "" && prevEmailAdd == EMAIL) {
      STATUS = "Child";
    }
    if (STATUS == "" && prevEmailAdd != EMAIL) {
      STATUS = "Parent";
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(i + 2, 4).setValue(STATUS);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.

Comment: Really, i already try on mine, and it's showing what are you want, then i will tell the wrong is, the out put just "value" instead of" values", and should put on the inside of loop, and the lasting is erase your checker that resulting continue, it will showing the results, but still wrong results, but is showinh

Comment: I tried it again and removed all other stuff I have and now it seems to work. Not sure what was wrong but when I was testing it, the result column all shows "Parent". Thank you for input and will mark it as the answer.